# Unable to click on element in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW7Dj.png)

I am working on a project, where I need to click on the split button (arrow head).

Below is the HTML:

```html
<table id="ext-comp-1006" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn support-servicedesk-sb caseMru standardObject mruIcon support-servicedesk-sbactive x-btn-noicon" style="width: 250px; height: 26px;">
   <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
     <tr>
        <td class="x-btn-tl">
          <i>&nbsp;</i>
          </td>
        <td class="x-btn-tc"></td>
    <td class="x-btn-tr">
       <i>&nbsp;</i>
     </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="x-btn-ml">
          <i>&nbsp;</i>
        </td>
    <td class="x-btn-mc">
      <em class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on" id="ext-gen100">
      <button type="button" id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text">
         <div class="mruIcon"></div>
         <span>Cases</span>
    </button>
   </em>
</td>
   <td class="x-btn-mr">
     <i>&nbsp;</i>
  </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="x-btn-bl">
        <i>&nbsp;</i>
</td>
   <td class="x-btn-bc"></td>
<td class="x-btn-br">
   <i>&nbsp;</i>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

My code to click on split button:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("x-btn-split")).click();
```

I tried with `id` also but it is throwing the *couldn't find the element* error.

Comment: Have you tried with id?

Comment: I tried with id...but throwing error...couldn't find the element.

Comment: Is your button within an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath('//button[@id="ext-gen33"]')).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me:

```
 System.out.println(browser.findElement(By.className("x-btn-split")).getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println(browser.findElement(By.className("x-btn-split")).getAttribute("className"));
        browser.findElement(By.className("x-btn-split")).click();
```

Once you executed above steps you will see the it actually prints the classname and id so its is working. If you can provide on click functionality then we can again check the script.

HTML I have used:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <em class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on" id="ext-gen100">
    <button
            type="button" id="ext-gen33" class="x-btn-text">
            <div class="mruIcon"></div>
            <span>Cases</span>
        </button></em>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Check full source code here:
https://github.com/jagdeepjain/selenium-recipes/blob/master/src/org/example/jagdeep/recipes/SplitButton.java

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is clicking on the first button, not the second button.

Comment: Please provide the correct HTML it will help in tackling the problem.

Comment: <em unselectable="on" class="x-btn-split" id="ext-gen100"><button type="button" id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text"><div class="mruIcon"></div><span>Cases</span></button></em>

Comment: remain HTML
</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i></i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i></i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i></i></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: `<html>
<body>
   <form>
      <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <em unselectable="on" class="x-btn-split" id="ext-gen100">
    <button type="button" id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text">
       <div class="mruIcon"></div>
       <span>Cases</span>
      </button>
     </td>
     <td class="x-btn-mr">
      <i></i>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="x-btn-bl">
    <i></i>
    </td>
    <td class="x-btn-bc"> 
    </td>
    <td class="x-btn-br">
    <i></i>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Hi Jadgeep, I have added the full html code above and image too. Please have a look and help me in this regard..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to add required CSS and javascript reference otherwise split button will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath instead of className. Write xpath with className.

try below code for button click.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em[@class='x-btn-split']/button[1]")).click();
```

or

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='x-btn-text']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. First code is working but clicking on the first button. Second code is getting error:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='x-btn-text']"}
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: How many buttons are there in your html code..? Depends button number you should change the index in my first code.

Comment: I changed the index to 2, but its unable to find the element.